# Assertion Failed error when using CPrintDialog in VisualStudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, modal-dialog

```
void CPrintProjectDlg::OnBnClickedButton1(){
  CPrintDialog dlg(FALSE);
  dlg.DoModal();
}
```

I implemented a PrintDialog when click Button1.

All are working well but when I close(click `OK` or `Cancel`) of `CPrintProjectDlg`(MainDialog), it is showing Assertion Failed error.

[image: Error Image]

UPDATE: `CFileDialog` is working well.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? Have you tried changing your default printer? Have you tried release build? Maybe someone else can provide more specific advice.

Comment: If you click the [Retry] button on that dialog, it should take you to line 430 of `"wincore.cpp`". Show what it's got in there. Call stack window may have more information as well.